# Regarding Javascript prompt box

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i'm currently developing a simple GUI for my mozilla plugin using JSP. In that Gui,i want to create a prompt box with two input fields with drop-down list option. Is it possible with javascript prompt box option?

Answer (score 3):

Not possible with the default `window.prompt();` function but you can roll your own overlay or use something like the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to do this with pure JS prompt boxes, but you can use a library like [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

Comment: Hm. Not possible? And jQuery UI or Bootstrap written using not pure JS? I would say - it is much more complicated if you write in pure JS. But not impossible)

Comment: @FAngel I mean it isn't possible to use pure JS popup boxes (i.e. alert, confirm, prompt), edited to make this clear.